# Compare two unsorted files and print unique elements from each file

Tags: design-patterns, unix, grep, ksh, matching

File1:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
17 18 19 20
```

File2:

```
9 10 11 12
21 22 23 24
1 2 3 4
17 18 19 20
```

I'm new to unix and I'm trying to obtain the unique rows from each file and output them into a new file, not printing the duplicates, files are Unsorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `sort -n` and `uniq -u`:

```
$ sort -n file1 file2 | uniq -u

5 6 7 8
13 14 15 16
21 22 23 24

# Redirect to file3
$ sort -n file1 file2 | uniq -u > file3
```

**Edit:**

```
$ awk '{u[$0]++}END{for(k in u)if(u[k]==1)print k}' file1 file2

5 6 7 8
21 22 23 24
13 14 15 16
```

Here `u` is the name of an associative array, you could name it anything *(I choose u short for unique)*. The keys *(k)* in the array are the lines in the files so every time a duplicate line is seen the count is increased. After the array is built we loop through the array and only print the key if it was only seen once, this code should help clear it up:

```
$ awk '{uniq[$0]++}END{for (key in uniq)print uniq[key]": "key}' file1 file2
2: 9 10 11 12
1: 5 6 7 8
1: 21 22 23 24
1: 13 14 15 16
2: 17 18 19 20
2: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: This works great, is there a way to have the output file sorted all in one command?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without sorting? Or is sorting necessary?

Comment: If you're input files are not sorted then you must sort to get the output in sorted order.

Comment: What I meant was, is there a way to output the unique rows without using the sort command on file1 and file2?

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help. However I'm unsure of the letters k and u in the above awk statement. Can you clarify what they represent?

Comment: Thanks everything has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a set of unique rows from *both files as a whole*:

```
sort -u File1 File2 > File3
```

UPD: `-u` might be specific for GNU coreutils. If your sort doesn't support it, see answer from @sudo_O.

UPD2: it turned out that @sudo_O interpreted the question differently: I assumed that duplicate lines should be included once, he assumed that they should be removed. If I'm right, than `sort|uniq` is the alternative for non-GNU `sort`. Otherwise, `sort|uniq -u` is the best solution so far.

Comment: `sort -u` is the same as `sort | uniq` not `sort | uniq -u` the difference is `uniq -u` prints the unique lines, i.e lines with no duplicates where as `sort -u` doesn't print the duplicates in the output so the ouput is unique, it's subtle but try both to see what I mean.

Comment: @sudo_O thanks. It turns out that we understand the question differently.

Comment: Yes I agree, the question is not clear at all.. you could even interpret it as `sort -u file1 > file3; sort -u file2 >> file3` which is just `sort file1 file2 > file3` as there are no duplicates in each individual file only the combination of both. We will have to see if the OP want's the unique lines or a unique list of the lines.